# How to rotate the Texture Region in LibGDX?

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

everyone I need to know how to rotate the texture region 180 degree i.e

```
birdRight = new TextureRegion(texture, 153, 0, 17, 12);
        bird.flip(false, true);
```

this gives me the bird which is facing rightside and now I need "birdLeft" so that the bird face faces to the left side .
I have got through some stuff but unable to find the solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
birdRight = new TextureRegion(texture, 153, 0, 17, 12);
birdRight.flip(false, false);

birdLeft = new TextureRegion(texture, 153, 0, 17, 12);
birdLeft.flip(true, false);
```